# Android emulator Failed to establish connection to ADB server

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I'm running Debian Wheezy on a thin client and I'm trying to start the Android emulator. I can build images so that's all working.

I've created a device called Nexus6 with the following

- Android 5.1.1
- CPU: Intel Atom (x86_64)
- Skin: HVGA
- RAM: 3072
- VM Heap: 32

I start my adb server

```
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

I try starting the emulator like so;

```
/media/data/utils/andriod/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd Nexus6
```

I get this error

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "192.168.200.191:7.0".
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  17
  Current serial number in output stream:  18
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 192MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 768MB
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "192.168.200.191:7.0".
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  17
  Current serial number in output stream:  18
adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server
console on port 5556, ADB on port 5557
```

When I start the adb server it's starting on a machine with IP 192.168.200.4, but my thin client is working on 192.168.200.191. When I start any command it usually starts that command using the server, but for some reason the emulator is using the local terminals kernel (most likely as it's trying to use KVM I think).

Is there a way to force the emulator to look for the adb server on the 192.168.200.4 machine?